# Why is `epic` badge silver?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was just curious,
why is **epic** a silver badge if only 73 users have been awarded with it?

For example:
*Silver*
Epic - 73

*Gold*
Electorate - 193

---

Edit:
My point was to reduce the level of **epic**, like "hit the daily reputation cap on 30 days" so it becomes some what *at par* with other *silver* badges.

Comment: There are only 67 pundits, and it's a silver badge too.

Comment: @mmyers :) Came to my mind, but IMO "pundit" badge doesn't say _much_ about programming prowess (comments with score > 10 may be due to poster's wittiness or may be the comment was funny :), so it being a silver badge is justified IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [Epic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/145/epic) is the tinfoil version of [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary), which is gold.

Comment: :) but still, _epic_ is tough to achieve compared to other silver badges.

Comment: @nvl, but then we should introduce a unique material to each badge, since each one is tough compared to some badges, and easier comared to others.  Wolfram badges, Platinum badges, Wooden badges, etc...

Comment: @Pavel: Actually, that'll be fun. Should be a `feature-request`.